# how to combine facet_grid and ggstatsplot::grouped_ggbetweenstats?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way we can combine ggstatsplot::grouped_ggbetweenstats and facet_grid to get multiple plots in one scale, something like below?
[image]

```
data<-data.frame(technology=(a,a,a,a, b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d), rate=c(2,5,7,9,2,5,7,9,2,5,7,9,2,5,7,9),return=c(20,15,20,30,50,13,10,8,7,9,11,23,17,20,13,16))
```

Comment: Please provide example input, the expected output is not clear, I don't see any scatterplot.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964137/ggstatsplot-subtitle-output-in-faceted-ggplot) shows how to combine ggstatsplot with ggplot facets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, it is not possible to combine `ggplot2::facet_grid()` with `ggstatsplot::grouped_ggbetweenstats()` (or any `grouped_` functions actually) because the latter **doesn't** output a `ggplot` object.

`ggstatsplot` uses a wrapper around `cowplot::plot_grid()` function (called `combine_plots()`) in the backdrop to arrange the individual plots and any adjustment you want to make to how individual plots are arranged in the combined plot can be made in the `grouped_` function itself using `...` argument. 
For example, see the documentation for `grouped_ggbetweenstats()` function here-
https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/reference/grouped_ggbetweenstats.html#arguments

Comment: Is it possible to collect the statistics of grouped_ggbetweenstats() and saved into data frame ?